# How to search range with intervals in Python

Tags: python, range

I've been given a project and although I've managed to get it to work, part of it looks very messy and I can't think of what I'm sure is a simple fix to it. My knowledge of programming is minimal so most Google searches for it have confused me and I don't really know how to define what I want. Anyone here is the code:

```
(if x in range(25,76) or x in range(125,176) or x in range(225,276) or
    x in range(325,376) or x in range(425,476) or x in range(525,576) or
    x in range(625,676) or x in range(725,776)):
```

I think you can see what I'm trying to do but I've had to list it as separate ranges each time, help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Note that `x in range(25, 76)` can also be spelled `25 <= x < 76`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option for shortening a lot of `or`s is to use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any), something like:

```
if any(x in range(start, end) for start, end in [(25, 76), (125, 176), ...]):
```

or just use arithmetic, if the values will always be integers:

```
if any(start <= x < end ...):
```

Alternatively, as you seem to have a regular pattern of ranges (i.e. between `25` and `76` in every hundred), you could use modulo (`%`) to strip away the hundreds:

```
if x % 100 in range(25, 76):
```

and add in `x < 776` if that's a fixed upper limit

Comment: Couldn't you just write `any(start <= x < end ...` and avoid searching in a list/generator?

Comment: @imaluengo that would work too, as long as `x` will always be an integer (`50.1`, for example, would give different results). In 3.x, searching in a `range` is `O(1)`, so if that's the case the efficiency isn't so bad.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about O(1) in python 3. That is interesting, thx for the tip!

Comment: @imaluengo *only* in 3.x, though - both `range` and `xrange` in 2.x are `O(n)` for membership testing.